# Adding row to another table before inserting a row

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

I have a tag model like this:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

and an image model like this:

```
class Image(models.Model):
    image_name=models.CharField(max_length=40,unique=False)
    ...
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
```

It is currently taking the primary key of the tags table in the array instead of the string values like this:

```
{
    "image_name" : "abc.png",
    "tags" : [1, 2] 
}
```

However, I want to be able to create a new image with POST request with multiple tags, something like this:

```
{
    "image_name" : "abc.png",
    "tags" : ["logo", "abc"] 
}
```

When I do this, I want logo and abc to be inserted into Tags table automatically.

Is ManyToManyField correct way to do this? If so, how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> By default nested serializers are read-only. If you want to support write-operations to a nested serializer field you'll need to create create() and/or update() methods in order to explicitly specify how the child relationships should be saved

Source: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers